# Transforms to ArcGIS API geojson output and geopandas series/dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, geojson, geopandas

The following GET yields a result you can view via Postman and/or geojson.io (NOTE: you need cookies, which are pasted at the bottom of this post):

```
url_geojson = "https://services6.arcgis.com/GklOjOaok2jR6aKf/ArcGIS/rest/services/NM_OG_ROWs_Linear_031417/FeatureServer/0/query?f=geojson&where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&orderByFields=FID%20ASC&outSR=102100&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=4000&cacheHint=true&quantizationParameters=%7B%22mode%22%3A%22edit%22%7D"
```

In the following GET call, another GIS API call yields just a json response with additional info in regards to the transformations that need to be applied to the geometry objects generated from the geojson call:

```
url_json = "https://services6.arcgis.com/GklOjOaok2jR6aKf/ArcGIS/rest/services/NM_OG_ROWs_Linear_031417/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&orderByFields=FID%20ASC&outSR=102100&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=4000&cacheHint=true&quantizationParameters=%7B%22mode%22%3A%22edit%22%7D"
```

Note that only difference is the `f` parameter (json and geojson).

The output of the json request has a section with the following output:

```
{
    "objectIdFieldName": "FID",
    "uniqueIdField": {
        "name": "FID",
        "isSystemMaintained": true
    },
    "globalIdFieldName": "",
    "geometryProperties": {
        "shapeLengthFieldName": "Shape__Length",
        "units": "esriMeters"
    },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolyline",
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102100,
        "latestWkid": 3857
    },
    "transform": {
        "originPosition": "upperLeft",
        "scale": [
            0.0001,
            0.0001,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "translate": [
            -20037700,
            -30241100,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },...
```

I assume these are the parameters that I need to use to change the output coordinates of the geojson request, which are (as a single example) this:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "EPSG:3857"
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "exceededTransferLimit": true
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 1,
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -11533842.1198518,
                        3857288.84408179
                    ],
                    [
                        -11534147.0371623,
                        3857067.64072161
                    ]
                ]
            },...
```

I have managed to take the geojson output and assign to a pandas dataframe and apply the scaling transform with the following command:

```
main_gdf_clean['geometry'] = GeoSeries.scale(main_gdf_clean['geometry'],
                                             xfact=0.00001, yfact=0.00001,
                                             origin=(0,0))
```

At this point, I'm lost on how to apply - as listed above in the json output - the translation parameters. I've tried the following command, and it yields wildly incorrect result to geometry objects:

```
GeoSeries.translate(main_gdf_clean['geometry'], xoff=-20037700.0, yoff=-30241100.0)
```

Based on what I've presented here, can someone suggest a way to apply the translation transform properly or go about this process in a different way?

```
      header = {'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=umzghudgzvz22wpo3a0bgeoq; OCDUserPreference=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',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'
}
```